# previewController:shouldOpenURL does not call in iOS 10 (Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

iOS 10 below delegate method does not fire.

```
- (BOOL)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *)url forPreviewItem:(id <QLPreviewItem>)item{
    return true;
}
```

Actually when I open pdf file from QLPreviewController, if there is available any link inside the pdf file, it will be opened when user tap that link. It is working on iOS 8,9. But latest iOS version(iOS 10) does not work.

Are there any special way to call above delegate method?

Comment: i am having the same problem...Any Update?

Comment: try with another pdf link. some PDF's links do not work in iOS 10.